# change background color of another component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have two components in different files. In component A I want clicking the button to change the background color and change the border color of a  element in the other component.
Example:

```
//componenteA.js
import React from 'react';
import style from '../componentes/cabezal.module.css';

let num1 = 1;
let diaynoche = ()=>{
  let bt1 = document.getElementById("bt1");

  if(num1 == 1){
    bt1.style.marginLeft = "35px";
    //Here I would like to create the code to change the background color or the border color of the <div id="cont1">       

    num1 += 1;
  }
  else{
    bt1.style.marginLeft = "0px";

    num1 = 1;
  }
}    

class Cabezal extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

  }

  render(){  
    return(
      <header className={style.hd}>
        <h1 className={style.titulo}>Aprendizaje autodidacta</h1>
        <div className={style.contExtdk}>
          <div className={style.contIntdk}>
             <button className={style.bth} id="bt1" onClick={diaynoche}></button>
          </div>    
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }  
}
export default Cabezal;


//componenteB.js
import React from 'react';

class Contenido extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div id={style.contenido}>
        <div className={style.sect1} id="cont1"></div>
      </div>
  )};
}
export default Contenido;
```

Is there a way to do it with React or should I use Javascript? How can I do it with Javascript?
Thanks for the help!